# PHP não pega informação do campo de telefone

Tags: php, html, formulário, phpmailer

Estou criando um formulário para enviar e-mail direto de uma site, por meio do `PHP`. Porém, quando adiciono o campo para colocar o telefone para contato o código `PHP`, parece não reconhecer o campo e não pega as informações desse campo.
Fiz alguns testes no código em `PHP` e se eu coloco alguma outra variável no campo de telefone o mesmo aparece no e-mail e se eu uso o campo de telefone em outra variável o mesmo não da para aparece a informação.

Código em PHP:

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['phone'])       &&
    empty($_POST['name'])       ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "Campo preenchido incorretamente!";
    return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'contato@slothsystem.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "E-mail enviado por  $name";
$email_body = "E-mail de contato enviado por $name \n";

$email_body .= "\nNome: $name
\nTelefone: $phone
\nE-mail: $email_address 
\nMensagem:\n $message \n";



$headers = "From: $email_address\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

return true;
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form  name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" action="contact_me.php"  method="post"> 
        <!--name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" required="required">
          <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required="required">
          <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
      </div>

       <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefone" required="required">
          <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea name="message" id="message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Mensagem" required></textarea>
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="success"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: falta o name dos inputs em quase todos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente o que estava faltando era o atributo `name` dos inputs.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form action="contact_me.php" method="post">
  <!--name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" required="required">
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required="required">
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefone">
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Mensagem" required></textarea>
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="success"></div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: mesmo adicionando o atributo de "name" nos campos continuo sem receber o que esta escrito no campo de telefone.

Comment: Fiz o teste aqui com o mesmo código PHP que você postou e quando eu mando imprimir a string $email_body imprime tudo certinho. usando o código HTML acima não deu nenhum problema

Comment: faça o seguinte, comente todo o código PHP e apenas mande executar essa função e cole aqui o retorno dela:
var_dump($_POST)

Comment: Agora esta funcionando, muito obrigado Phelipe. :)